# Error in verilog, coding for CSHM Filter using generate statement

Tags: filter, compiler-errors, syntax-error, verilog, xilinx

```
    module CSHM #(parameter data_width=8,order=4)
(y,in,clk,reset_n);

wire [data_width-1:0]coeff[0:order-1];
output reg signed [2*data_width-1:0]y;

input clk,reset_n;
input signed[data_width-1:0]in;
integer i;
wire [15:0] product1,product2,product3,product4,product5,product6,product7,product8;
wire signed[3:0]lsboutputcoeff;
wire signed[7:4]msboutputcoeff;
wire signed[2:0]lsbcount,msbcount;
wire signed[2:0]lsbselect,msbselect;

wire signed[2*data_width-1:0]muxoutput,shiftoutlsb,shiftoutmsb;
  wire [3:0] lsbcoeff;
  wire [7:4] msbcoeff;
    //reg [7:0] this_coeff;

wire [2:0]inputshift;
wire signed[15:0]muxout;
wire signed[15:0]leftshiftone,leftshifttwo,leftshiftthree;
wire [15:0]outputshift;




bankofprecomputers b1(.product1(product1),.product2(product2),.product3(product3),.product4(product4),.product5(product5),.product6(product6),.product7(product7),.product8(product8),.in(in));

genvar count;
generate        
 assign  coeff[0]= 8'd1;
 assign coeff[1]= 8'd2;
 assign coeff[2]= 8'd3;
 assign coeff[3]= 8'd4;
 for(count = 0; count < order ; count = count+1)
 begin : gen_loop
    assign lsbcoeff = coeff[count][3:0];
      assign msbcoeff = coeff[count][7:4];



shifter s1(.lsboutputcoeff(lsboutputcoeff),.msboutputcoeff(msboutputcoeff),.lsbselect(lsbselect),.msbselect(msbselect),.lsbcount(lsbcount),.msbcount(msbcount),.lsbcoeff(lsbcoeff),.msbcoeff(msbcoeff));
   end
endgenerate
mux8_1msb m1(.muxoutput(muxoutput),.msbselect(msbselect),.product1(product1),.product2(product2),.product3(product3),.product4(product4),.product5(product5),.product6(product6),.product7(product7),.product8(product8));

mux8_1LSB m2(.muxoutput(muxoutput),.lsbselect(lsbselect),.product1(product1),.product2(product2),.product3(product3),.product4(product4),.product5(product5),.product6(product6),.product7(product7),.product8(product8));              

inverse_shifter is1(.shiftoutmsb(shiftoutmsb),.muxoutput(muxoutput),.msbcount(msbcount));

inverse_shifter_LSB is2 (.shiftoutlsb(shiftoutlsb),.muxoutput(muxoutput),.lsbcount(lsbcount));



      always@(negedge clk)
        begin
      y = shiftoutmsb+shiftoutlsb;
          end



endmodule
```

When im trying to synthesis , im getting error as

> Multi-source in Unit  on signal lsbcoeff3; this signal is
>   connected to multiple drivers.
>
> Multi-source in Unit  on signal lsbcoeff0; this signal is
>   connected to multiple drivers.

**If im wrong anywhere , please guide me**

Answer (score 1):

`lsbcoeff` and `msbcoeff` are shared across the static-unrolled generate loops, therefore you have parallel assignments onto these nets. To resolve the issue, you need to make the nets unique for each loop. This can be done two different ways.

1. Array the nets:

   ```
   wire signed [2:0] lsbcount [0:order-1];
   wire signed [2:0] msbcount [0:order-1]
   for(count = 0; count < order ; count = count+1) begin : gen_loop
     assign lsbcoeff[count] = coeff[count][3:0];
     assign msbcoeff[count] = coeff[count][7:4];
     ...
   ```
2. Localize the nets by declaring them inside the generate loop: ***Note:** with this aproach, the nets will not be accessible outside its loop scope.*

   ```
   for(count = 0; count < order ; count = count+1) begin : gen_loop
     wire signed [2:0] lsbcoeff = coeff[count][3:0];
     wire signed [2:0] msbcoeff = coeff[count][7:4];
     ...
   end
   // lsbcoeff and msbcoeff cannot be accessed outside of the loop
   ```

Comment: @SugureshKumarArali, update the code in the question. I doubt you are getting the exact same error message if you made the changes correctly. I do see the same multi-driver issue with `lsboutputcoeff` and `msboutputcoeff`. Reminder, the loops in a generate blocks run in parallel, not procedural.

Comment: oh ok, but i have 4 coefficients, which  has to split into LSB and MSB Coefficients, which has to be update every cycle , please guide me , its a CSHM  Filter architecture

Answer (score 0):

The **for** loop is more or less like same lines repeated n number of times.

```
for(count = 0; count < order ; count = count+1)
 begin : gen_loop
    assign lsbcoeff = coeff[count][3:0];
      assign msbcoeff = coeff[count][7:4]; 
....
```

So @Suguresh, your original code is having the issue.

As correctly pointed by **Greg**, you need to correct this. For your code, the solution 1 looks more apt. Can you change the code and post updated again to re-check ?